# How to spawn a cowboy server in a test?

Tags: elixir, cowboy, ex-unit

### Background

I have a specific test where I need to spawn a cowboy server listening on port 8082 that returns some static responses.

### Objective

Normally I would spin up a cowboy process in my `application.ex` file like this:

```
   def start(_type, args) do
     children = children([{Cowboy, scheme: :http, plug: MyServer, options: [port: 8082]}])

     opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]
     Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
   end
```

But the code I am working on is not an application, so I can't do that.

My objective is to use the [`setup_all`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#setup_all/2) callback of ExUnit to do this, however I don't know how to do it or if it is possible.

### Questions

1. How can I start a cowboy server in ExUnit?

Comment: can't you just put `Supervisor.start_link` for cowboy in your `setup_all`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging around, I found that there is a library called [`bypass`](https://hexdocs.pm/bypass/Bypass.html) that already covers this use case.

This solution was also confirmed by Elixir's community, which seems to suggest it as well: https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-spawn-a-cowboy-server-in-a-test/36686